# Криво отображается валидация для DatePicker

Tags: kendo

[Исходник в Dojo.](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Dmitry05/AGina)
Валидация (срабатывает если поле пустое. Поставить фокус на датапикер, потом убрать) для датапикера отображается криво. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы она отображалась под полем ввода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указать позицию для сообщения валидации можно с помощью такой разметки:

```
<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="birthdateContender"></span>
```

В вашем случае это будет так:

```
<div id = "bdateContender">
    <label>Дата рождения: </label>
    <input type="text" id="birthdateContender" class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header k-textbox" name="birthdateContender" data-bind="value:birthdateContender"/><br />
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="birthdateContender"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно. В Dojo предупреждение валидации действительно показывает под датапикером, как и нужно. Но в браузере (ff, chrome) - всё по старому.

Comment: Dojo для отображения использует тот же ваш браузер, а не какую то магию. Если у вас отображение в проекте не соответствует тому, что вы видете в доджо, значит у вас какие то проблемы в проекте. Например стили перекрывают что то или вы неверно перенесли к себе в проект решение.

Comment: Да. Странно, сегодня перезапустил проект, и валидация отображается как надо. Видно кэш не почистил и подтягивался старый скрипт. Спасибо Мстислав, который раз выручили уже).